# sql delete column

Tags: sql, sql-delete

There are four columns in the table

I want to delete if column a4 is null

[image]

So why can  I write code

```
delete MAX(ID) as a1,a2,a3,a4 
FROM dbo.T07StokDurum where a4 is null
GROUP BY DesenKodu,Ebat
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Just to clarify. Do you only want to delete those where a4 is null and where there exists records with the same (a1,a2,a3) but have a value for a4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your delete syntax is incorrect.  See [SQL DELETE Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_delete.asp).

```
DELETE FROM dbo.T07StokDurum WHERE a4 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to delete the whole line where the column A4 is null, just:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.T07StokDurum where a4 is null
```

..Would do. No need for the rest of the code you wrote. Unless you're trying to do something else not specified.